# Solving $\log_x(x^2+4x)>-1$

Tags: logarithms

I'm stuck looking for a solution for this. Any hint?
$$
\log_x(x^2+4x) > -1
$$

It looks like
$$
x^2+4x > 1/x
$$
which I cannot solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

$$\log_x(x^2+4x)>-1=\log_xx^{-1}\implies \begin{cases}x^2+4x>\frac1x&,\;\;\text{if}\;\;x>1\\{}\\x^2+4x<\frac1x&,\;\;\text{if}\;\;0<x<1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Very nice hint (+1)